# "Can't load inbox" bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, top-bar

I can open my reputation and the Stack Exchange dropdown, but when I go to hover over my Inbox, it loads for a fraction of a second and then disappears.

I had 3 notifications and when I clicked on the inbox symbol, they disappeared, so it assumes I've read them but I have not.

Here is a GIF of the problem:

[image]

I have managed to reproduce this in all of the browsers I have installed (Chrome, Edge, IE, Firefox and Opera).

I get an error in the console:

> ```
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/topbar/inbox
> ```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Anything coming up in the dev tools?

Comment: Yes I did sorry, forgot to put it in the post @Oded

Comment: What happens when you go directly to https://meta.stackexchange.com/topbar/inbox ?

Comment: I get the "Oops, something bad happened, it's not you it's us" error message @Oded

Comment: OK, I see the exception. Will dig into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should now be fixed.

We had some issues with Documentation tags being merged/aliased that broke some notifications.

Comment: Documentation. It is always Documentation.